# How to score victory against government in exile?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

TLDR: country without any army/terrain is doing evil stuff with diplomacy, I want them dead or at least to leave me alone.

---

As unaligned Iran, I started war of conquest against Turkey. Few hundred thousand deaths in war Kingdom of Romania joined the effort... what Romania? They got devoured by red menace early on, few years later Iran, German and Japan forces had big party at Ural ski resorts, conquered twice, no sign of Romania is left, or so I thought.
[image: WHAT ROMANIA?!!?!]
Decisive armored push ends the war, Turkey surrenders. Can't put Romania to grave because they have nothing to give up. Apparently 13 cargo ships and bunch of derelict fighter planes is enough to wage a war against upstart empire...

[image: UGH]
Once Turkey surrenders, I am left in war against... what? Lets sign peace, nope... I need to be losing to sign peace... Then stupid AI and strict diplomacy strikes in, Romania is too scared to fight alone so they call in my good friend, Commonwealth (leaving them without any oil...). And then I am in war against all Allies because reasons. Tried to google out solution, it gave up and stopped responding, ugh...

Is there a way to end this bloodshed? I have Tibet to conquer ;)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the current war status and participants? You'll get to a peace conference only once you defeat all primary members of the war.

Comment: @Alien-47 Peace conference occurred after fall of Turkey, Only Turkey was available in panel with provinces. Romanian ghost kept being at war against me. I'll add screenshot when near my PC.

Comment: @Alien-47 screenshot added.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly - currently you're in a war against Allies, Romania being a member of them? I see that you can't do anything during the peace conference. Don't you mind postins a screenshot of participants of a currently ongoing war? I wan to understand who fights who.

Comment: My current best guess is this: Romania guaranteed Turkey, so they entered the war to protect them. At some point Romania joined allies, and some magic of war merging happened. So now you have 2 wars - one (finished) with only Turkey, one ongoing with the Allies. So Romania won't quit until Allies are defeated.

Comment: @Alien-47 weirdly, I am not in war against Allies, just Romania. They joined Allies about 1939, resulting war is not me against faction, just me against Romania and whatever pals they bring in (probably because its Romania that declared on me). More screenshots incoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Country in faction won't capitulate, even if it wants to, as long as there are any major countries left standing. In my case Allies are hold together by USA and UK.

Major countries are:

- Germany
- Italy
- Japan
- Soviet Union
- France
- United Kingdom
- United States
- Hungary (in Pact of Rome)

[image: politics...]

But its nothing that bunch of console commands won't overcome (<kbd>~</kbd> opens console)

Puase game

1. Pause game to avoid side effects
2. `tdebug` enables tooltip where you can see three letter country tag (here is [list](http://heartsofiron.wikia.com/wiki/Country_tag) because its government in exile has no land to point at)
3. `tag ROM` to become Romania
4. `allowdiplo` to allow all diplomatic actions
5. Leave faction in diplomacy with faction leader (UK in my case)
6. `tag PER` to return to Iran
7. `allowdiplo` and `tdebug` again to disable cheats

This caused Romania to surrender right away, which lead to peace conference which composed of half the world passing hundred turns just to get one province because no country left standing scored even one victory point over Romania. Game diplomacy at its finest ;)

Comment: Thanks to @Alien-47 for pointing me in right direction :)

Comment: Okay, so it looks like because of the fact that Romania was in another war together with the Allies against Germany, they couldn't be peaced out in your war. Diplomacy sometimes can be not that obvious, sadly(

Comment: @Alien-47 from what I understand, only thing that matters is being in faction with non-capitulated major power. Just simple hard rule to simulate historical governments in exile. Not an issue for allies/axis/commies, and neutrals are not really focus of this game so no one cares about poor Iran ;)